# how to avoid Nill class for this

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting entity_name is nill class for this

```
<%= f.text_field :transferred_entity_id ,id: "transferred_entity_id", :value => @employee.entity_name,class: "form-control"%>
```

This is the code I'm having. Can any tell me how to avoid `nil`
class for this using the down code

```
<%= f.text_field :transferred_entity_id ,id: "transferred_entity_id", :value =>  @employee.other_entity.entity_name.present? ? @employee.other_entity.entity_name : [nil],class: "form-control" %>
```

while im editing im rendering to another page i need to do hardcode
for this, using terminal operator condition then only it will work can
any one suggest me how to do

Answer (score 1):

Use [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

```
@employee.other_entity.try(:entity_name)

nil.try(:entity_name)
#=> nil
```

Comment: @Pasha -- refer: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Object.html#method-i-try